# AnimationDrawable getting null on getBackground()

Tags: android, null, animationdrawable

I am trying to animate a sample program with the following code:

```
AnimationDrawable animation;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.loading);

    ImageView animatedImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.animation);
    animatedImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animate_bag);
    animation = (AnimationDrawable) animatedImage.getBackground();
}


public void startAnimate(View v) 
{
    if (animation != null)
        animation.start();          
} //eof OnClick
```

The XML file is:

```
    <Button android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Animate"
        android:onClick="startAnimate" />
     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/animation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/animate_bag" />


</LinearLayout>
```

The problem I have is that animatedImage.getBackground() returns null.

Will appreciate your hints :-)

Thanks,
 Simon

Comment: Hi, I know this is old but did you find any solution? thanks

Answer (score 6):

If getBackground() returns null, use getDrawable() method.

```
//animation = (AnimationDrawable) animatedImage.getBackground();
animation = (AnimationDrawable) animatedImage.getDrawable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you ;)

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.loading);

    final ImageView animatedImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.animation);
    animatedImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animate_bag);


    animatedImage.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) animatedImage.getDrawable();
            if (frameAnimation != null) {
                frameAnimation.start();
            }
        }
    });
}
```